# Creating color tables for floating point raster maps in GDAL?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, gdal, colortable

I've got a script that dumps a floating point raster that I'd like to automatically color.  Currently I load this raster in ArcGIS Desktop or QGIS and manually create a color table every time I re-run my model.  I'd like my model to automatically create a nice color table, but the only functionality I can find is to create a color table for integer only rasters.

My approach so far is to output 2 rasters, one with floating point values rendered in grayscale and a second integer raster that has the colors on it.  I can flip between the two to see values, but it's far from optimal.

Is there a technique to procedurally create floating point color tables in GDAL that automatically load with QGIS or ArcGIS Desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For arcgis 10 you could save a layer file with symbology applied and then use a python script to change the data source as part of the output of the originating script. See [layer.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Updating_and_fixing_data_sources_with_arcpy_mapping/00s30000004p000000/).

For QGIS the [1-band raster colour table](http://www.bc-consult.com/freebies.htm) plugin might suit: *"After selection of a single band raster ... launch this plugin to generate a colour table ... The colour table is made of the combination of a colour palette ... and a colouring method (the way to relate a colour index in the palette to a real value in the raster). "* It's not automatic but may alleviate the work a bit.

Alternatively you may be able to work some magic with [rgb2pct utility](http://www.gdal.org/rgb2pct.html) which has the option of loading a colour pallette from an external file.